# How to release Unity Memory from iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-management, unity-game-engine

I am creating and iOS app which contains Unity game as a module when user clicks on play game from menu, every thing is working once user clicked on exit I releases the UnityAppController and removed its objects from memory but when user choses to play again application got crashed with exe_bad_excess.

Is there any way to remove UnityAppController from memory and reinitialise it so that the overall memory footprint got reduced once user is not playing the game.

I am using XCode 8.2 and Unity 5 code.

Answer (score 0):

just push your view controller with coding main stoaryboard then it's not crashes.. in unity

below is the code

UIStoryboard *storyBoard;
    storyBoard                      = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ViewController *mainVC        = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ac"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainVC animated:YES];